# Linear temporal logic question

Tags: logic, kripke-models

I am curious about what if we have this Kripke model

[image]

and I am trying determine the set of worlds where  $\Box\Box p$ is satisfied

This is the part I am confused about when we have $\Box$ I am assuming it means for the next state or it is also for the initial starting place $a$

For example it would mean for this path $p$ -> $p, q$ is valid  $\Box p$. This would be true if the other path wasnt false right? $p$ -> $r$ not valid.

The other question is when we have $\Box\Box p$ the initial state is not counted like this $p$ -> $r$$(\Box p)$ -> $p$$(\Box\Box p)$

---

This is how I think I would solve it and this are my thoughts on how I arrive at the conclusion. I have added an extra $\Box$ so everyone can see how I arrive at the conclusion to make it easier to correct me if I am wrong

[image]

Comment: What is $\varphi$? You seem to have some serious confusions about Kripke semantics - I can't understand anything you wrote. You should not be "assuming" what $\square$ means - the meaning of $\square$ should be clearly defined in whatever book or lecture notes you're learning from. My suggestion is that you review that, and reconsider your question. Final comment: It seems like you're thinking about a Kripke model as something like a finite state automaton (with the talk of "initial starting place" and "next state"). This is not the right way to think about it.

Comment: @AlexKruckman $\Box\Box p$ and $\Box$ is for always G, in the lecture. I am just not sure if we take into account the starting place in $a$ for $\Box\ p$ because in the lecture it is says it is false for a for $\Box\ p$ and true for $p$ and I summarize that this is the case because always is used for the next state as in it needs to be always true $p$ -> $p$ for any taken path. So for $a$ we have two possible paths to take and $p$ -> $p$ is only true for one of which leads to it being false for $a$

Comment: (1) If it's $\square\square p$, not $\square \square \varphi$, then you should edit the question to fix this. (2) I have no idea what "$\square$ is for always G" means. (3) What makes you think that $a$ is the starting place? You're asked to find the set of worlds where some sentence is true, and to determine whether a sentence is true at a world $w$, you treat $w$ as the starting place. (4) what do you mean when you say "p -> p is true"? Presumably not the implication!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take this step by step.

What is the set of worlds where $p$ is true? Answer: $\{a,b\}$.

We have three worlds, $a$, $b$, and $c$. In your diagram, the letters inside the circles are the propositions which are true at those worlds. So $p$ is true at $a$ and $b$, but not at $c$.

What is the set of worlds where $\square p$ is true? Answer: $\{c\}$.

$\square p$ is true at $w$ iff $p$ is true at every world accessible from $w$. And we determined that $p$ is true at $a$ and $b$. So $\square p$ is false at $a$ (since $c$ is accessible from $a$), $\square p$ is false at $b$ (since $c$ is accessible from $b$), and $\square p$ is true at $c$ (since the only world accessible from $c$ is $a$).

What is the set of worlds where $\square\square p$ is true? Answer: $\{b\}$.

$\square \square p$ is true at $w$ iff $\square p$ is true at every world accessible from $w$. And we determined that $\square p$ is only true at $c$. So $\square \square p$ is false at $a$ (since $b$ is accessible from $a$), $\square \square p$ is true at $b$ (since $c$ is the only world accessible from $b$), and $\square \square p$ is false at $c$ (since $a$ is accessible from $c$).

Comment: I know it is an old post, but I added an image trying to understand your explanation. I am taking the class currently and it would be nice if you could highlight if there are still any issues left

Comment: @zellez11 I can't follow the illustration. Is there anything unclear about my answer?

Comment: I was trying to showcase your answer in the illustration I guess i got it wrong if you cant follow it. Meaning I didnt fully grasp the answer :(

Comment: @zellez11 Well, it wasn't obvious what was going on with the color coding, but I think I understand now. I think what was confusing me was that you have two rows of your diagram starting with $a$. If you just had one $a$ on the left, branching to $b$ and $c$, it would make more sense.

Comment: So everything is correct beside me having an extra row starting with a

Comment: @zellez11 yes, once interpreted correctly, it looks right.